# Statistical significance between groups of a summation variable

Tags: statistical-significance

The general problem is that I have an calculated variable that represents agreement across parts. The variable is a summation in the form (part/count of parts)^2 for possible parts. The summation variable is between 0 and 1. How would I go about testing for significant differences between calculated part agreement for two study conditions?

The specific situation involves gestures that study participants used to accomplish a particular task. Here, agreement means the number of times a particular gesture was used over the total number of gestures for each task (squared as per above)--summed for all gestures per task. I would like to calculate whether or not agreement differs significantly per gesture across two groups (study compares two conditions) and am unsure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but it sounds like your "summation" variable is quite similar to a proportion, in which case you can use a t-test; however, the "squared" aspect may mess that up; still the t-test is relatively robust.

I would first make plots; one thing to do here is parallel box plots. Another is to create two overlaid densities. If the variables look roughly normal (they can't be exactly normal because they are bounded) then a t-test. If not normal, there are always permutation tests and other non-parametric tests (e.g. Wilcoxon).

Comment: Thank you! A corollary question really relates to how to perform the t-test in this particular situation. I am looking at the agreement between different tasks by group (again, two groups). An example is as follows: for the "select item" task, the horizontal group has 0.36 agreement and the vertical group has 0.33 agreement (that is, there is one observation per group per task). Is there any way to test the difference between the groups for specific tasks or can I only look at differences in the average task agreement by group? I think the latter, but this isn't very interesting.